# Is there any ways to build an apk by using Gradle and not by using IDEs like Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I am in need of generating APKs by using GRADLE system but not by using IDEs like Android Studio or Eclipse. Will it be possible to use Gradle system as a stand alone manner? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is absolutely possible because Android Studio actually uses the very same Gradle commands in order to build the APK.
Assuming you already setup the signing configuration you can use:

```
./gradlew :app:assembleRelease
```

or if you are on Windows:

```
gradlew.bat :app:assembleRelease
```

In general you can use

```
./gradlew tasks
```

in order to explore all the tasks you can run from command line.

Comment: Bro, could you please tell me what is signing configuration means? I can google it but, It would be more helpful when I get the answer from the expert directly. Thanks

Comment: Please refer to the full documentation linked in the other answer :)

Comment: I will check that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I am in need of generating APKs by using GRADLE system but not by
>   using IDEs like Android Studio or Eclipse

**YES** you can build an APK without **IDE** with terminal.

you can Build  and Run android project from the Command Line. Please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Comment: Glad for your inputs. I will look into it.